# TypeError: command.execute is not a function. (After typing !rps on discord channel)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I try to use !rps, discord shows me that there is no command and I get somethink like that in the console
I don`t know do I need to change something in my index.js code or in my rps.js code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7GkI.jpg

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.command = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands');

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.command.set(command.name, command);
    }
}

const prefix = '!';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot jest online');

    client.user.setActivity('Minecraft')
});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.command.has(commandName)) return;

    const command = client.command.get(commandName);

    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('Nie ma takiej komendy!')
    }

});

client.login("TOKEN");
```

And the rps.js code, I tried to move rps.js to other folder but it does not solve the problem

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "rps",
    description: "rock paper scissors command",
    usage: "!rps",

    async run(bot, message, args) {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("RPS")
            .setDescription("React to play!")
            .setTimestamp()
        let msg = await message.channel.send(embed)
        await msg.react("")
        await msg.react("✂")
        await msg.react("")

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['', '✂', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        }
        const chices = ['', '✂', '']
        const me = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.lenght)]
        msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, error: ["time"] }).then(async (collected) => {
            const reaction = collected.first()
            let result = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Result")
                .addFields("Your Choice", `${reaction.emoji.name}`)
                .addField("Bots choice", `${me}`)
            await msg.edit(result)

            if ((me === "" && reaction.emoji.name === "✂") ||
                (me === "✂" && reaction.emoji.name === "") ||
                (me === "" && reaction.emoji.name === "")) {
                message.reply('You lost!');
            } else if (me === react.emoji.name) {
                return message.reply(`It's a tie!`);
            } else {
                return message.reply('You won!');
            }
        })
            .catch(collected => {
                message.reply('Process has been canceled, you failed to respond in time!');
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Imgur is currently returning an over capacity error, this is why we include any images within the question not as extern links.

Answer (score 0):

In your `rps.js` file, you are defining the function to be run as `run` but in your `index.js` file, you are using the `execute` function so you can either change how you run the command in your main file or you can change the function name in your command file. Another place where you could get an error is the arguments you pass. In your main file, you are passing two arguments to your command file, `message` and `args` while in your command file, you are expecting three, `bot`, `message` and `args`. So you can either change the order of the arguments you pass or you can just remove the bot parameter in the command file:

Comment: I changed to 'async execute' and it  still didn`t work ;/

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: https://imgur.com/bc48DBB

Comment: Error looks like

Comment: Change `let msg = await message.channel.send(embed)` to `let msg = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]})`

Comment: Still not working, error is still with keyword „send” as I show you on screen

Comment: Also just noticed. In your `const me = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.lenght)]`, you've misspelled the word length.

Comment: I correct Word „length” but problem is still with Word”send” https://imgur.com/a/8xkhN94

Comment: Try console logging the message. If it returns undefined, then the problem is when we call the command

Comment: I change 'command.execute(message, args);' to 'command.execute(bot, message, args);' in index.js and error with 'send' word disappear but i have another error https://imgur.com/kNN37Y2

Comment: That's because, there is nothing called bot in your `index.js` file Just try `console.log(message)` and see what happens

Comment: Add you to what?

Comment: Like what? If you have any questions, you can just ask them all here

Comment: So where do i need to put this `console.log(message)` beacuse i dont understand this step

Comment: In your `rps.js` file

Comment: If it returns `undefined`, then the problem is not in the `rps.js` file

Comment: It returns 
"console.log(message);
            ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined"

Comment: Did you write this in your 'rps.js' file?. It has to be in your `command.execute`, not outside

Comment: but in `rps.js` I dont have `command.execute` - this is in `index.js`

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled it. It should be in the `async execute()` in your `rps.js` file

Comment: I put it here and it dont return anything https://imgur.com/Deh56He

Comment: Anything as in it returns `undefined`?

Comment: I dont know do we think about same thing but it looks like https://imgur.com/ajxCdNc